# Could not load type 'NewSite.MvcApplication' kentico

Tags: c#, iis, kentico

i'm pretty new to this.i newly installed kentico cms and it hosted in IIS server whenever i try to access the localhost website i get this error.[image]

this is my Global.asax.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

using Kentico.Web.Mvc;

namespace NewSite
{
    public partial class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            // Enables and configures selected Kentico ASP.NET MVC integration features
            ApplicationConfig.RegisterFeatures(ApplicationBuilder.Current);

            // Registers routes including system routes for enabled features
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            // Registers enabled bundles
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}
```

this is my Global.asax

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="NewSite.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

what did i missed here,any help please.i'm stuck here in hours now

Comment: Do you really have `NewSite.MvcApplication` class in your application? If not please create the same and compile the project. It will work for sure. Also Check that the project output path (project properties / Build) is set to bin and not bin\Release or bin\Debug. For some reason IIS (VS development Server or Local IIS) always accesses the libraries from the bin directory (and won't look up for subdirectories)

Answer (score 1):

finally i found a solution and i don't know this is the best way to fix this because i'm new to this.

i changed

```
Codebehind="Global.asax.cs"
```

to

```
CodeFile="Global.asax.cs"
```

in Global.asax file

and it's working.

please let me know if this is a not good solution.